# pyramidal modification of ruby array

Tags: arrays, ruby, logic

I'm writing a script that takes two paramenters, a 2-D array (all 0's and 1's) and a maximum vertical distance n, and returns a modified array. Such that that if n = 3 the following array

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

returns

```
[[0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
 [0,0,1,1,1,0,0],
 [0,1,1,1,1,1,0],
 [1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
 [0,1,1,1,1,1,0],
 [0,0,1,1,1,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,0,0,0]]
```

(the array input can have any rectangular dimension; any element can be a 10).

My idea is to clone the original array, scan it for 1's, and map the changes into the clone. I'm trying to map the changes first to the right side and then to the left of the original 1.

I got the following to work, which changes the central column of the array:

```
a = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

cloned = a.map(&:clone)

n = 3

a.each.with_index do |whole_row, row|
    whole_row.each.with_index do |cell, column|
        if cell == 1

            #center column
            row_path = row - n
            (n*2+1).times do
                unless (cloned[row_path][column]).nil?
                    cloned[row_path][column] = 1
                end
                row_path += 1
            end

        end
    end
end

cloned
```

However, when I try to iterate this procedure towards the right, I'm getting `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`. Where am I messing up the logic here?

```
a = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

cloned = a.map(&:clone)

n = 3

a.each.with_index do |whole_row, row|
    whole_row.each.with_index do |cell, column|
        if cell == 1

            #central column & right side
            row_path = row - n
            column_path = column
            repetition = 2 * n + 1
            (n+1).times do 
                (repetition).times do
                    unless cloned[row_path][column_path].nil?
                        cloned[row_path][column_path] = 1
                    end
                    row_path += 1
                end
                repetition -= 2
                column_path += 1
                row_path += 1
            end
        end
    end
end

cloned
```

(My idea is to implement this procedure twice, to the right and then left of the original array).

Comment: You need to define "maximum vertical distance" in words (by editing your question). The example is not sufficient. Also, what do you meant that any element can be a 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example I have assumed that the "vertical distance" between elements at `[i,j]` and `[k,l]` is given by the method:

```
def dist((i,j),(k,l))
  (i-k).abs + (j-l).abs
end
```

in which case "rectangular distance" would be a better descriptor. If this assumption is incorrect, you need read no further.

For your example:

```
a = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

n = 3
```

after defining the method `dist` above, you may construct the desired array as follows:

```
nrows = a.size
  #=> 7
ncols = a.first.size
  #=> 7

Array.new(nrows) do |i|
  Array.new(ncols) do |j|
    nrows.times.any? do |k|
      ncols.times.any? do |l|
        a[k][l] == 1 && dist([i,j],[k,l]) <= n
      end
    end ? 1 : 0
  end
end
  #=> [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
  #    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
  #    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  #    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Alternatively, you could do it the other way around (with `nrows` and `ncols` computed).

```
b = Array.new(nrows) { Array.new(ncols,0) }
nrows.times.each do |i|
  ncols.times.each do |j|
    next unless a[i][j]==1
    nrows.times.each do |k|
      ncols.times.each do |l|
        b[k][l] = 1 if dist([i,j],[k,l]) <= n
      end
    end
  end
end                 
b
```

Both of these approaches could be made more efficient by limiting the rows examined (as a function of the target row and `n`), and for each row considered, by limiting the columns examined (as a function of the row, the target row and column and `n`).

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because you are trying to access an item in the sub array of the array index that doesnt exist.

This line -- `cloned[row_path][column_path].nil?` here the `row_path` doesn't hold any value in some iterations, and that is because you are incrementing it twice.

Removing the increment from `(repetition).times` should fix it.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Considering Dwijen's answer, I tweaked the script so that there's no nil inside the index when testing. I was getting an error until I added to proceed `unless (row_path > cloned.length - 1 )` This passes the test:

```
a.each.with_index do |whole_row, row|
  whole_row.each.with_index do |cell, column|
    if cell == 1

      #central column & right side
      row_path = row - n
      column_path = column
      repetition = 2 * n + 1
      counter = 0
      (n+1).times do 
        (repetition).times do
          unless (row_path > cloned.length - 1 ) || cloned[row_path][column_path].nil? 
            cloned[row_path][column_path] = 1
          end
          row_path += 1
        end
        counter += 1
        repetition -= 2
        column_path += 1
        row_path = row - n + counter
      end

      #central column & left side
      row_path = row - n
      column_path = column
      repetition = 2 * n + 1
      counter = 0
      (n+1).times do 
        (repetition).times do
          unless (row_path > cloned.length - 1 ) || cloned[row_path][column_path].nil? 
            cloned[row_path][column_path] = 1
          end
          row_path += 1
        end
        counter -= 1
        repetition -= 2
        column_path -= 1
        row_path = row - n - counter
      end

    end
  end
end
```